# Extension Method On Casted Type

Tags: c#, enums

I have a simple enum, that looks something like the following:

```
public enum Brand
{
    [Description("Friendly Brand Name")]
    Brand1,

    [Description("Once Again")]
    Brand2
} // eo enum Brand
```

I have an extension method with the following signature:

```
public static string ToDescription(this Enum self) { /* .. implementation .. */ }
```

A quick check in LINQPad shows me that:

```
Brand brand = Brand.Brand1;
brand.ToDescription().Dump();
```

... all works as intended.

Now comes the fun part.  In my code, at this point I want to iterate through the values of an arbituary enum (in this case `Brand`), and I've only got a `System.Type` to go on.  First, I implemented a quick extension method for `Array`:

```
public static IEnumerable<object> AsEnumerable(this Array self)
{
    foreach(object o in self)
        yield return o;
} // eo AsEnumerable
```

Knowing that my type is an `Enum`, I iterate through the values thusly (where `type` is the actual `Brand` enum type)  (Note: `CastTo` is just a shorthand extension method for `Convert.ChangeType`):

```
foreach (var enumValue in Enum.GetValues(type).AsEnumerable().Select((e) => e.CastTo(type)))
    Console.WriteLine(enumValue.ToDescription());
```

And I get the following runtime error:

```
'MyNameSpace.Brand' does not contain a definition for 'ToDescription'
```

Debugging, in the immediate window the type of `enumValue` is indeed `Brand`.  I am guessing this may have something to do with the way extension methods work - or that I am missing something obvious.  Perhaps there's a workaround?

Comment: Are you talking about compile time error?

Comment: Have you tried using this method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx instead of the dynamic variant

Comment: Are you talking about compile time error or runtime error?

Comment: This is a runtime error - sorry, I should have been more explicit.

Comment: Can you post a repro? I can't reproduce it without how `CastTo` is implemented and its signature. Or just post `CastTo` method would be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `CastTo` just changes the type at runtime, why not use the `Cast<T>` instead?

```
foreach (var enumValue in Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<Enum>())
  Console.WriteLine(enumValue.ToDescription());
```

Comment: Then too, the AsEnumerable he wrote is <object> when it could be <T>

Comment: @AlexBeisley I think he uses `AsEnumerable` just to convert it to `IEnumerable`, and then use his `CastTo` to convert it back to enum but it's a way around and the type is determined only at runtime.

Comment: @KingKing, you're absolutely correct.  The `AsEnumerable` was superflous, and the cast to `Enum` did the trick nicely!  Not sure how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward approach I can think of is a `Dictionary` of descriptions:

```
public static class YourClass
{
    public enum Brand { Brand1, Brand2 }
    private static Dictionary<Brand, string> Descriptions {get; set;}

    static YourClass()
    {
        YourClass.Descriptions.Add(Brand.Brand1, "Friendly name 1");
        YourClass.Descriptions.Add(Brand.Brand2, "Friendly name 2");
    }

    public static string ToDescription(this Brand brand) 
    {
        // error checking left out
        return YourClass.Descriptions[brand];
    }
}
```

This approach will also allow you to expand easily, for instance it's easy to support multiple languages in your "descriptions", or leverage a DAL ...

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods are really just a compile-time syntax sugar for some static method, which you could instead have called directly. So they depend on the statically known type of the variable.

Rather than using your `AsEnumerable` method, note that `Array` is already an `IEnumerable`, System.Linq provides two useful extension methods on `IEnumerable` to get an `IEnumerable<T>`:  `Cast<T>` and `OfType<T>`. These both result in typed enumerables, so you can do:

```
foreach (var enumValue in Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<Enum>()) {
    Console.WriteLine(enumValue.ToDescription());
}
```

In fact you can also make use of the old implicit cast in `foreach`:

```
foreach (Enum enumValue in Enum.GetValues(type)) {
    Console.WriteLine(enumValue.ToDescription());
}
```